# No compiler warning for returning a reference to local variable

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

Using:

```
g++ -Wall -ansi foo.cpp
```

I get the warning

> foo.cpp:31: warning: reference to local variable ‘x’ returned

from the function :

```
int &bar(int x) {
     return x;
}
```

but, removing that function from the file, I get no warning from the following function:

```
int &get_max(int x, int y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

Why does the compiler allow this?

Comment: Seems to have been added in GCC 5.1.

Comment: It doesn't *allow* it. It simply fails to warn about it. `clang 3.4` does report it in both cases.

Comment: gcc has a similar glitch for C code: http://pastebin.com/eU6MwPbn

Comment: pfff VS2013 code analyzer also does not report it!

Comment: The compiler isn't required to warn you every time you do something stupid.

Comment: @chris looks like a bug, `gcc` catches it w/ optimization turned on but not w/o optimization.

Comment: @Brian sure, but `gcc` seems to want to catch these cases and it does when optimization is turned on so it looks like a bug that the `gcc` team probably wants to fix but we won't know w/o a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug, the warning is inconsistent, if we turn on optimization in [gcc 5.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/28YjVbQ5YUmy217K) it does catch this case:

```
warning: function may return address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 return x > y ? x : y;
                    ^
```

while without optimization [gcc misses it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ko0kevY3QyIyIUan).

So the best thing to do would be to file a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). If they don't believe it is a bug or won't fix it then at least there will be a reference for others having the same issue.

Comment: Meh; a lot of checks in GCC depends on optimization being on. This would be neither the first nor the last.

Comment: @T.C. it still looks like a bug, I have been told several times, if you find what you believe is a compiler bug then file a bug report. Worse that can happen is that it ends up not being a bug or they don't want to fix it but at least others can now find the report and have that for a reference.